Merge two dataframes in R, utilizing one as a dictionary gives more rows
I have two dataframes in R.
One of them is huge (200k rows) and one of the columns ("fields") has a total of 160 possible values that repeat themselves.
Then I have another dataframe that acts as a dictionary. This dictionary has two columns, the first one, "field" which comprises around 130 of the 160 possible values from the data$fields column, and a second column called "categories", with 8 possible values.
I want to add to the original dataframe, a new column, called "category", which would have the corresponding category to the field value.
For example purposes:
Data
Field     | Value
Germany     1
Germany     1
Germany     1
USA         1
USA         1
Japan       1
Australia   1


Dictionary:
Field     | Category
Germany     Europe
USA         America
Japan       Asia


After merging
Field     | Value | Category
Germany     1       Europe
Germany     1       Europe
Germany     1       Europe
USA         1       America
USA         1       America
Japan       1       Asia
Australia   1       NA


So this is what I'm doing:
# Merge the original dataframe with the dictionary dataframe based on the 'fields' column
dat <- merge(data, dictionary, by = "field")

However, the new dataframe goes from 200k rows to 240k. Why is that?

merge(df1,df2, all = TRUE)

thx @ThomasisCoding. However, this gives more rows than before, why is that?

then you should use all.x = TRUE

@ThomasisCoding, then I have 287k rows, how is that possible?

Check your dictionary. This suggests you have duplicate values in Field in the dictionary. If that doesn’t seem to be the case, please update your post with sample data that produces the same problem.

Your data is apparently growing more and more each time you try something new - are you assigning it back to the same object every time or starting fresh?  I recommend keeping a "pristine" df1 and df2 to work from while you experiment.

With this sample data it is not possible to have more rows post-merge than before, whether doing a left-join, full-join, or whatever. I second zephryl's suggest to check for duplicates in dictionary$Field.

Since you deleted your other question I can't comment there anymore, but I would still strongly urge you not to mix data types within one column. Even if you can't condense one (apparent) observation onto one row, having dates in the same column as medication names means you can't use either dates or medication names well.

You can merge using left_join:
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = "Field")

where df1 is the data frame with Field and Value, and df2 is the 'dictionary' data frame.

My original dataframe has 204k rows and the new created one has 287k rows, how is that possible?

You will need to post a sample of the data so I/we can check what's going wrong (might be grouping, might be trailing factor level...)

Some test data so we can work out what's going on:
(note I'm using df1 and df2 as per the comments and suggestions on your original post to avoid confusion with your real objects, given I suspect they hold the key to this.)
df1 <- data.frame(Field = c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "USA", "USA", "Japan", "Australia"),
                  Value = 1)

df2 <- data.frame(Field = c("Germany", "USA", "Japan"),
                  Category = c("Europe", "America", "Asia"))


Straightforward left join as seen in Chris Ruehlemann's answer:
dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = "Field")

      Field Value Category
1   Germany     1   Europe
2   Germany     1   Europe
3   Germany     1   Europe
4       USA     1  America
5       USA     1  America
6     Japan     1     Asia
7 Australia     1     <NA>


using base R's merge:
merge(df1,df2, all = TRUE)

      Field Value Category
1 Australia     1     <NA>
2   Germany     1   Europe
3   Germany     1   Europe
4   Germany     1   Europe
5     Japan     1     Asia
6       USA     1  America
7       USA     1  America

test to help work out why your version's going badly:
# are all the dictionary versions of 'Field' represented in the data set?
all(unique(df2$Field) %in% unique(df1$Field))
[1] TRUE

# There should be no duplicated Field in df2 (dictionary)
length(df2$Field) == length(unique(df2$Field))
[1] TRUE

Do you get the same?

Isn't this exactly the solution I posted a good half hour before you posted yours?

@ChrisRuehlemann Ha! yes, part of it is.  I managed to miss that and only noticed the discussion thread.  I'll add a note.
